Collision failed in turtle graphics ping-pong game: the ball is not bouncing after it hits the wall
I wrote a collision function to make the ball bounce back after it hits the wall. It's called wall_collision in ball.py.
Issue
The collision function called wall_collision does not work as expected:

it doesn't go further than the wall like it should, but
it just starts going right along the wall instead of bouncing.

Code
main.py
Here the collision function is called:
from turtle import Screen
from paddle import Paddle
from ball import Ball
import time

x_pos1 = -350
x_pos2 = 350


ball = Ball()
screen = Screen()
paddle1 = Paddle(x_pos1)
paddle2 = Paddle(x_pos2)

game_on = True

#screen set up
w = 800
h = 600
screen.setup(w, h)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Pong Game")

# movement
screen.listen()

screen.onkey(key="w", fun=paddle1.up)
screen.onkey(key="s", fun=paddle1.down)

screen.onkey(key="Up", fun=paddle2.up)
screen.onkey(key="Down", fun=paddle2.down)

screen.tracer(0)


while game_on:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    screen.update()
    ball.move()
    ball.wall_collision()   # call of collision function

screen.exitonclick()


ball.py
Here the collision function is defined:
from turtle import Turtle
import random

DISTANCE = 5
new_heading = 70  # change of direction after collision 

class Ball(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rand_turn = [self.left(60), self.right(60)]

        self.shape("circle")
        self.setpos(0, 0)
        self.color("cyan")
        self.penup()
        self.speed("slow")
        self.move()
    

    def move(self):
        self.setheading(new_heading)
        self.wall_collision()
        self.forward(DISTANCE)
        
        

    def wall_collision(self):
        if self.ycor() > 280 or self.ycor() < -280:
            new_heading = 360 - self.heading()  # bounce and change direction
            self.setheading(new_heading)
            self.forward(DISTANCE)

paddle.py
from turtle import Turtle



class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x_pos):
        super().__init__()

        self.x = x_pos
        
        self.penup()
        self.color("white")
        self.shape("square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.setpos(x_pos, 0)
        


    def up(self):

        if self.ycor() > 245:
            pass
        else:
            new_y = self.ycor() + 35
            self.goto(self.x, new_y)


    def down(self):
        if self.ycor() < -230:
            pass
        else:
            new_y = self.ycor() - 35
            self.goto(self.x, new_y)

What I tried
I tried to make the starting heading of the ball to a variable called new_heading as I thought that the heading was the issue. So I tried to change it in the wall_collision function but that did not change anything.
So I came here for help.
Also, if there are any recommendations to make the code better do mention those.
What is wrong with the code, particularly with the collision function?

360 - heading is not the correct way to "bounce" the direction. (Think about what happens if the heading is 180.)

Collision and bouncing from a plane object like a wall is explained here: mathematics - Determine Resulting Angle of Wall Collision - Game Development Stack Exchange

An example of a ball bouncing from the screen/wall and change in angle is given in this Python brick-breaker clone on GitHub.

See Python Turtle based Pong game for a potential bounce implementation. Even if setheading worked here, it'd do a 180 turn, not a half-turn bounce.
